# Create a GIF from an HTML animation

Tags: html, css-animations, animated-gif, google-web-designer

**THE PROBLEM**

I've created an HTML animation using [google web designer](https://www.google.com/webdesigner/), then I need to export my project as a GIF. Google web designer doesn't provide any tool to export as GIF so:

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I've tried to record my screen (using quick time player for MAC) crop and cut the result and then convert the MP4/MOV file to the GIF.

**CONCLUSION**

I'm not very satisfied with the result, the resulting GIF is very big (HTML is like 20KB and the GIF is 500+KB ) and the quality is mediocre.

Can someone provide me with a better solution or something to improve the quality of the result?

Comment: Taking a record appears to be the way to go, unfortunately: http://superuser.com/questions/434649/how-to-take-a-css-animation-from-a-browser-and-export-a-gif-of-it

Comment: this is not a answer.

Comment: How long is your animation? How smooth (number of frames per second) do you need it to be? An animated GIF will definitely always be larger than an HTML/CSS animation.

Comment: I was hoping for something different from screen capture..... seems nope. Anyway the animation is 7 sec long at 24 fps

Comment: well, this is the downside of .gif animations, they are always big and don't have a good quality. if the usecase allows it, i would advise to use the mp4 video.